# Request Mobile Site after requesting Desktop Site Safari

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, websites

I selected Request Desktop Site on a web page and now I want to go back to the mobile version. How?

I Google’d and got 20 results explaining how to get the Desktop version, but none how to go back.

Using Safari on iPad.

Comment: Try clearing your cache because the website is remembering the setting from a cookie.  You can also go incognito mode to test this theory.

Comment: some sites you can just add `m.` before the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by closing the tab, opening a new one and opening the site again there.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by clearing the sites Web Data.

1. Go to Settings
2. Safari
3. Advanced
4. Website Data
5. Tap on edit
6. Find the website which you want to switch to mobile version. Then, tap on the red button to the left of it and hit Delete.
7. Click Done at the top to confirm

The website should now be mobile!

Or you can close the tab and open a new one.

Comment: Can you add an example for a site which works with the `m` trick?

Comment: The `m` “trick” is less and less useful with each passing day.  If there are websites that *dont* use [Responsive Design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp), they are obsolete - like 5 years out of date.  Having a different site depending on whether your users have a mobile or desktop device is inefficient and backward.

Answer (score -2):

I know m.linkedin.com works for substituting the ‘m’ prefix...